# Hangman python game

Tags: python

I am writing a python based terminal game of Hangman for a project.
Currently, the correctly guessed letters and letters remaining are displayed correctly if the player makes a correct guess or an incorrect guess.

I am having an issues displaying the letters if the player makes an invalid guess.
I have a for loop that displays the guessed letters and unguessed letters which works as expected.
However, I have an if else statement at the start of the function that determines if the user inputs a correct character.
The problem I have is that the letters are only displayed if the user makes a valid entry.
So if the user repeats a letter, inputs a number instead of a letter, or inputs multiple characters, the code to display the letters doesn’t run so the user wont be able to see their “gamescreen”.

This is the main function for the main game.

```
def new_game(category, difficulty):
    """
    Starts a new game which takes the category and difficulty
    parameters chosen by the user to generate a word from the spreadsheet.
    """
    # Generate the word the player is trying to guess
    random_word = random.choice(
        SHEET.worksheet(difficulty + "_" + category)
        .get_values().pop()).upper()
    # Print the category and difficulty level chosen by the user
    print(f"Category: { category.capitalize() }")
    print(f"Difficulty level: { difficulty.capitalize() }")
    guessed_letters = ""
    wrong_guesses = 0
    print_hangman(wrong_guesses)
    # Print random word for testing.
    print(f"your word is: {random_word}")
    # Display blank letters in word for user.
    print(len(random_word) * " _ " + "\n ")
    # Create a loop that ends when the player loses. Break if player wins.
    while wrong_guesses < 7:
        player_choice = input("Please pick a letter...: \n").upper()
        print(f"Category: { category.capitalize() }")
        print(f"Difficulty level: { difficulty.capitalize() } \n")
        print_hangman(wrong_guesses)
        clear()
        # Prints error message if player choice is not a letter from a-z.
        if not player_choice.isalpha():
            print(
                f"{player_choice} is not a valid letter... " +
                f"You have {7 - wrong_guesses} guess(es) remaining...")
            print_hangman(wrong_guesses)
            guessed_letters = guessed_letters + player_choice
            wrong_letters = 0
            # Prints the players guessed letters and remaining blank spaces.
            for letter in random_word:
                if letter in guessed_letters:
                    print(
                        f" { letter.upper() } ", end=""
                        )
                else:
                    print(" _ ", end="")
                    wrong_letters += 1
            print("")
            print("\nPreviously guessed letters: \n")
            print(f"{list(guessed_letters.upper())}" + "\n ")
        # Print error message if player inputs more than one letter.
        elif len(player_choice) != 1:
            print(
                "Please input one letter at a time..." +
                f"You have {7 - wrong_guesses} guess(es) remaining...")
            print_hangman(wrong_guesses)
            print("\nPreviously guessed letters: \n")
            print(f"{list(guessed_letters.upper())}" + "\n ")
        # Print error message if player repeats the same letter.
        elif player_choice in guessed_letters:
            print(
                f"{player_choice.upper()} has already been guessed..." +
                f"You have {7 - wrong_guesses} guess(es) remaining...")
            print_hangman(wrong_guesses)
            print("\nPreviously guessed letters: \n")
            print(f"{list(guessed_letters.upper())}" + "\n ")
        # Runs if player makes a valid input.
        else:
            if player_choice in random_word:
                print(
                    f"Correct, {player_choice.upper()} is in the word! " +
                    f"You have {7 - wrong_guesses} guess(es) remaining...")
            else:
                # Add 1 to the wrong_guesses variable
                wrong_guesses += 1
                print(
                    f"Sorry, {player_choice.upper()} is not in the word... " +
                    f"You have {7 - wrong_guesses} guess(es) remaining..."
                    )
            print_hangman(wrong_guesses)
            # Adds all letters guessed by the user
            # to the guessed_letters variable.
            guessed_letters = guessed_letters + player_choice
            wrong_letters = 0
            # Loop that displays correct letters and letters remaining.
            for letter in random_word:
                if letter in guessed_letters:
                    print(
                        f" { letter.upper() } ", end=""
                        )
                else:
                    print(" _ ", end="")
                    wrong_letters += 1
            print(" ")
            print("\nPreviously guessed letters: \n")
            print(f"{list(guessed_letters.upper())}" + "\n ")
            if wrong_letters == 0:
                print(
                    colorama.Fore.GREEN +
                    "Congratulations, you won! \n"
                    )
                print(f"The word is {random_word.upper()}!\n")
                sub_menu()
                break
    else:
        print(
            colorama.Fore.RED +
            "\nSorry, you lose... Please try again...\n")
        print(f"The word was {random_word.upper()}...\n")
        sub_menu()
```

I’ve copied the loop into the first validity checker at line 391 to test and it does work.
I can also put the loop into the other error statements but this ends up making the code very bulky.
I’ve tried moving the loop into its own function but it is referencing other variables that are only in the new_game function.
I also tried to define an inner function but I couldn't get it to work, I had variables in the inner function that were needed in the outer function.

Any help on figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.
Also any other tips to clean up this code would be great if you notice anything ridiculous!
I have a lot of repeating print statements that I tried to avoid repeating but I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted unless I printed them out every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the for loop in its own function and pass it the variables it needs when calling it. The function might look like this:

```py
def display_letters(random_word, guessed_letters, wrong_letters):
   for letter in random_word:
      if letter in guessed_letters:
         print(
             f" { letter.upper() } ", end=""
             )
      else:
         print(" _ ", end="")
         wrong_letters += 1
         return wrong_letters
```

I'm not sure about this but could you not just have the letters display after you fall out of the if statement? As in, immediately after the if statement (but not in it) just run the for loop. That might work.